# How to use Python packages (GeoPandas, rioxarray) inside GRASS Python scripts?

Tags: python, grass-gis, geopandas, rioxarray, grass.script

I want to combine the functionality of GRASS GIS with other Python packages such as GeoPandas and rioxarray. My OS is Windows. It is possible to import other standard packages such as numpy and Pandas. When I run my script inside GRASS these modules are not found although they are installed in my (conda) base environment:

```
import grass.script as gscript
import numpy
import geopandas
```

`'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'geopandas'`

What do I have to do to make these packages available for GRASS?

Answer (score 2):

I found a workaround for this: Instead of running Python scripts from within GRASS one can call GRASS from Python in any environment (that contains the desired packages such as geopandas etc) following these instructions.

https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Working_with_GRASS_without_starting_it_explicitly#Python:_GRASS_GIS_7_with_existing_location

Basically the Python-Libraries are added to the system path, which makes them available as packages  (grass.script and others) and the GRASS location is configured for the GRASS libraries to work correctly. This approach has the advantage the the GRASS and Python console outputs are displayed in order.

I'd still be interested though how to change the Python-Interpreter GRASS is running in or how to add packages to the default interpreter that GRASS is using.

Note: I had to manually add my paths to the gisbase, as the code on the homepage didn't produce the correct strings. If you're using GRASS 8.x.x the procedure seems to be a bit different but should be also documented on the linked homepage.

Comment: I can not verify the "Module not found" error. When I start GRASS on my system, I can then, in the GRASS python console (or at the command line) run `import geopandas as gpd` without error. Can you specify what OS you are working on, and how you installed the python libraries?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I'm running Ubuntu 20.4. and installed the python libraries with conda